# How to import sections of a text file to four different strings

Tags: c++, import, text-files

I have a txt file split into four chapters/sections. I would like to import this txt file, with each section going to a different string variable. So section 1 of the file gets saved into string variable 1 etc.

These four variables are then sent to a different thread each, where I have a string searching algorithm set up to find a specified pattern.

Right now I have this, taken from a lecture's example code:

```
string filename = "JuteBook.txt";
string juteBook;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    ifstream f(filename, std::ios_base::binary);
    if (!f.good())
    {
        filename = "../" + filename;
        continue;
    }

    static const size_t start = 0;
    static const size_t amount = 0x1819;

    f.seekg(start);
    char buf[amount];
    f.read(buf, amount);
    juteBook.assign(buf, amount);
}

int juteBookLength = juteBook.length();

int calculation = juteBookLength / 4;
int finalNumber = round(calculation);
```

Comment: A StackOverflow question needs to be *much more specific* than this and should usually also include a [mcve].

Comment: @JesperJuhl I added some code that I previously used, however not much else I can add. Haven't gotten anywhere else with this

Comment: I'm a bit confused, your title speaks of 4 different strings, but your loop has 6 iterations and you always store it in the same string...

Comment: @Borgleader Yeah I didn't want to add the code at first as it was just an example from a lecture that I was using at first. But the first comment was asking for some more specificity or examples, and this is all I had. The problem is, I don't know how to separate the txt file into four different variables

Comment: What rules to you use to determine the end of the input sectons?

Comment: Why are you opening the file inside the loop?  Common practice is to open the file once, continuously read, then close.

Comment: You have an endless loop if your file is never found.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I just want to divide the txt file by 4, so I have 4 different even sections, then set it to the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
static const unsigned int  section_size = 0x1819;
char buffer[section_size];
std::string s1;
std::string s2;
std::string s3;
std::string s4;
// code to open file
f.read(buffer, section_size);
s1.assign(buffer, section_size);
f.read(buffer, section_size);
s2.assign(buffer, section_size);
f.read(buffer, section_size);
s3.assign(buffer, section_size);
f.read(buffer, section_size);
s4.assign(buffer, section_size);
f.close();
```

For only 4 reads, I decided to inline; IMHO, a lot more efficient than a loop.

The above code assigns the buffer to 4 variables per your post.

I could give a better answer, but I would need more information about the assignment and the content of the input file.  For example, are you to divide the file into 4 equal parts?  or divide by paragraph?  Can you use `std::vector` instead of separate variables?  Do you really **need** to have the all the file content in memory at the same time or can your process the file in chunks?

Comment: This solution kinda works. Yeah the file would be split into 4 equal parts. I can also use vectors, although I'm not super familiar with them. Not sure about the last question

Comment: I'm currently working with this solution, it's been pretty helpful so far. However when assigning the reads to each string, why are you using buffer and section_size in the argument list? Since buffer has been set to the same value as section_size above. I don't know what buffer does so I could be looking at this completely wrong

Comment: I am using `buffer` as a destination for the data from the file.  The `std::string` variables are your final string variables.  The buffers are memory and not necessarily C-Style strings (as the terminating NUL character, '\0', has not been appended or guaranteed).  Maybe, I don't understand your definition of *string*.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Cheers for the help